# Issue for uploading joomla plugin in 3.2.2

Tags: plugins, joomla

Continuously facing problem for uploading webmaster verification joomla plugin.

But getting the following error:

JLIB_FILESYSTEM_ERROR_WARNFS_ERR02.

Any kind of help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

This language string you mentioned translates into `Warning: Failed to move file!`.

You might be getting this due to various problems, for example:

1. Directory permissions aren't correct
2. File/folder ownership
3. TMP directory hasn't been defined correctly

Have a look at the following page which will give you an detailed insight:

http://docs.joomla.org/Why_can%27t_you_install_any_extensions%3F

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but i want to add plugin of webmaster in admin. So, how can implement....

Comment: You install it like any other Joomla plugin